# Embed Google Chrome or Firefox in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, firefox

It is possible to embed the 'Internet Explorer Web Browser' in an Excel Sheet using the Microsoft Web Browser Object. How does one Embed Google Chrome or Firefox in an Excel Sheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a project to provide a [Mozilla ActiveX control](http://www.adamlock.com/mozilla/control.htm) matching the IE Web Browser Control Interface as much as possible. I am not following the progress but its supported version seems dated.

As for Chrome you could check out [Chromium Embedded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) but it doesn't seem to support ActiveX so you would have to work something out using the .NET binding ([CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)) in combination with VSTO and WinForms.

I have used CefSharp with WinForms application and it works quite well. 
The samples are good for a quick start.

Comment: Mozilla Activex control link is dead. Use this: http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm . However, as renick said this is NOT FIREFOX. It is outdated and probably near to useless for todays web applications.